# Create rowspans with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I append the data from a json-object to a table:

```
var array1 = $.map(data, function (field, i) 
{
    return '<tr><td>' + field.date + '</td><td>' + field.art + '</td><td class="san' + field.art +'">' + field.text + '</td></tr>';
});

$('#TableBody').append(array1.join(''));
```

[image]

Actually this works pretty good and i get a output like this:

```
<tbody id="TableBody">
<tr><td>18.02.2014</td><td>D</td><td class="sanD">Was soll ich sagen</td></tr>
<tr><td>18.02.2014</td><td>DD</td><td class="sanDD">hallo</td></tr>
<tr><td>17.02.2014</td><td>R</td><td class="sanR">Erster Versuch</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

But i would like to have such an output: Means that same `field.date` have only one row:

```
<tbody id="TableBody">
<tr><td rowspan="2">18.02.2014</td><td>D</td><td class="sanD">Was soll ich sagen</td></tr>
<tr><td>DD</td><td class="sanDD">hallo</td></tr>
<tr><td>17.02.2014</td><td>R</td><td class="sanR">Erster Versuch</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

How can i achieve this? Thanks

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V2mmw/2/

Comment: Basically you want to "merge" the cells which have the same date?

Comment: Yes i mean remove the duplications of the same day and only make one big cell

Comment: can you change the data source, to include an additional field which contains the number of a particular date occurrence, or you need a script which scans and do the job?

Comment: I need the javascript to do the job! Do you have some idea? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ignore my previous thought, I was thinking in to many places in the same time. Let me think about it.

Comment: I had this idea, that after appending the data to the `tablebody` it would be possible to count how often each date is there: `$("td:contains('28.02.2014')").length` But then?? How do i edit my html with this info?

Comment: That will only work on 1 particular date. GIve me a bit of time please, trying to cock, babysit, speak on the phone and come up with an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function that does what you want:

```
function mergeSameDates() {
    var $firstItem, 
        sameCount = 0;
    $("#TableBody tr td:nth-child(1)").each(function (index, item) {
        var $item = $(item);
        if ($firstItem === undefined || $item.text() !== $firstItem.text()) {
            $firstItem = $item;
            sameCount = 1;
        } else {
            sameCount += 1;
            $firstItem.attr("rowspan", sameCount);
            $item.remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is an updated [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V2mmw/3/).

Comment: Thanks @zord Its a very clean solution! But do you think your solution is faster then the solution from @Alessandro?

Comment: I don't know. You should test the performance on your browser of choice, if that's your priority. I can only say my solution is cleaner, and you don't loose event handlers from the table (if you have any). Also my code is pretty easily can be generalized for _any_ column of _any_ table.

Comment: Thanks! I know it was kind of a stupid question but its really hard for me to choose the best answer! Thanks again! I will test it!

Answer (score 3):

I think that you need something like this, but i used `$.each` function:

```
var html = "";
var arr = new Array();

$.each(data, function (i, field) {    

    var rowspanTest = $.grep(data, function (elem) {
        return elem.date === field.date;
    }).length;    

    if(jQuery.inArray( field.date, arr ) == -1){    
        html += '<tr><td rowspan=' + rowspanTest + '>' + field.date + '</td><td>' + field.art + '</td><td class="san' + field.art +'">' + field.text + '</td></tr>';
        arr.push(field.date);
    }else{
        html += '<tr><td>' + field.art + '</td><td class="san' + field.art +'">' + field.text + '</td></tr>';        
    }
});

$('#TableBody').append(html);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alessandroaje/V2mmw/4/)

Comment: Thanks its a very good thought solution for my problem! I think its also faster then the solution from zord! What code do you prefer?

Comment: @JohnSmith my code is good to correct the table on moment when was created, you really need to test this to verify, but i think that my code is faster than Zords code

Comment: Thanks again alessandro, finally i choosed zords solution because it worked a little bit better! Have a nice night!